# How to split/divide a string of array into two groups with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm given an array of strings. Its a text with actions in brackets. Ex.

```
"John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him."
```

The end result I'd like would be

```
actionArray = "                                           [waves]

speechArray = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!'.       But she didn't hear him."
```

The actionArray would be spaced for each character so the action tag would be on top of the speechArray during the action. I've approached this problem using the following method.

```
var array = data.toString().split("\n");
  for(i in array) {
    var actionArray = "";
    var speechArray = "";
    for (var letter in array[i]){
      if (array[i][letter] == "["){
        actionArray += array[i][letter];
        letter++;
        while(array[i][letter] !== "]"){
          actionArray += array[i][letter];
          letter++;
        }
        if (array[i][letter] == "]"){
          actionArray += array[i][letter];
        }

      }

      if (array[i][letter] !== "["){

        speechArray += array[i][letter];
        actionArray += " ";
      }
```

So to extract the part of the string with the action brackets, I have an if method that finds "[" and if it does, it would add it to the actionArray, keeps with the if and adding to actionArray until it finds the closing tag "]"

It works, but the counter `letter` doesn't continue where I left off after finding the closing tag, so the entire string still ends up being copied to the speechArray. And then I end up getting something like this

```
actionArray = "                                           [waves]

speechArray = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!'.[waves] But she didn't hear him."
```

I'm new to Javascript, without the use of pointers I'm not sure how to approach this. Could someone point me tot he right direction? Thank you!

Comment: use regular expression with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. The names of your variables say "Array", but as you've written the values they look like strings.

Comment: posted a solution where you need one `replace` statement for each string (one statement for the actionString and one for the speechString). Take a look at it if you want to. If you have any questions leave a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Just have a variable that tells you if you're "inside" an action and assign accordingly:

```js
str = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him.";


let action = '',
    speech = '',
    inAction = false;

for (let char of str) {
    if (char === '[')
        inAction = true;
    if (inAction) {
        action += char;
        speech += ' ';
    } else {
        action += ' ';
        speech += char;
    }
    if (char === ']')
        inAction = false;
}


console.log(action)
console.log(speech)
```

And here's a more concise but far less readable solution with regexes:

```js
str = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him.";

let parts = ['', ''];

str.replace(/(\[.+?\])|[^\]\[]+/g, function (m, a) {
    parts[a ? 1 : 0] += m;
    parts[a ? 0 : 1] += ' '.repeat(m.length);
});

console.log(parts[1]);
console.log(parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this simple code snippet:

```
var data = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him."
var arr = data.split("");
var action = false;
var actionstr="",speachstr="";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]=='['){
            action = true
        }else if(arr[i] ==']'){

            actionstr = actionstr.concat(arr[i])
            speachstr = speachstr.concat(" ")
            action = false
            continue
        }
        if(action){
            actionstr = actionstr.concat(arr[i])
            speachstr = speachstr.concat(" ")
        }else{
            actionstr = actionstr.concat(" ")
            speachstr = speachstr.concat(arr[i])
        }
    }
    console.log(actionstr)
    console.log(speachstr)
```

The output should be:

```
                                           [waves]                          
John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!'        . But she didn't hear him.
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the below implementation,maybe it might be ok for you

```
var arr = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him."

var p = arr.split(/\s+/)

var c = p.map( value => {

    if (/^\[.*\]/.test(value) )
        return value;
    else 
        return " "
})

var command = c.join(" ");
var strings = arr.replace(/\[.*\]/, " ".repeat(command.match(/\w+/)[0].length))


console.log(command) 
console.log(strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with regular expressions.

First the easy part (speechString):

```
var speechString = string.replace(/(\[[^\]]*\])/gi, (v)=>' '.repeat(v.length));
```

it just replaces `[...]` with the number of spaces equals to the length of the match.

Now the harder part (actionString):

```
var actionString = ((string)=>{
    var ret = '';
  var re = /(\[[^\]]*\])/gi;
    var l = 0;
    while((m = re.exec(string)) != null) {
        ret += ' '.repeat(m.index-l) + string.substring(m.index, m.index+m[1].length);
        l = m.index+m[1].length;
    }
    return ret;
})(string);
```

it defines the same regularexpression to find the `[...]`, but uses the index (postion of the match) and the length of the match to build a string like expected.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/3o3z0puo/) is a working fiddle.

---

**EDIT** actionString can also retrieved by one single statement:

```
var actionString = string.replace(/([^\[]*)(\[[^\]]+?\])?/g, (v,p1,p2)=>{
  return (p1?' '.repeat(p1.length):'')+(p2||'');
});
```

Match all characters and a `[...]` expression and replace it with spaces in the length of the first group length appended with the p2 match.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()`, and `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\[.+\]/` to match character beginning within `"["` followed by one or more characters followed by and including `"]"`, `String.prototype.repeat()`

```js
let str = "John sees his neighbor and greets 'Hello!' [waves]. But she didn't hear him.";

let re = /\[.+\]/;

let match = str.match(re);

let res = " ".repeat(match.index) + match[0] 
          + " ".repeat(str.length - (match.index + match[0].length));

str = str.replace(re, " ".repeat(match[0].length));

let pre = document.querySelector("pre");

pre.textContent = res + "\n" + str;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: How about two or more "actions" in the same string?

Comment: @georg Did not considered multiple matches of `"[<characters>]"`. Does OP mention multiple matches of `"[<characters>]"` within text of original Question?
 The pattern can be adjusted to handle multiple matches by incrementing an index.

Comment: @georg Are you suggesting that we should we infer that requirement is for multiple matches of `"[<characters>]"` though that is not explicitly mentioned as a requirement at OP?